# Alpha image ontop of non alpha image

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have a PNG with a completely transparent background as well as semi transparent pixels around the main image (think shadows / blur).

On its own, it displays as I expect. If I use it on a web-page, the page background colour shows through the transparent and semitransparent pixels with the various levels of opacity. Good.

However, when I paste this alpha image into a separate PNG image ( which has no alpha ) in a new window in GIMP, the semi transparent pixels loose their alpha settings and become completely opaque.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Transparency never copies and pastes correctly in any software. Use whatever Place / Import your build of GIMP has instead

Comment: This is effectively a tech support question and will most likely be closed as such - but when you ask this somewhere else, please try to be more specific. Someone should be able to redo exactly what you did, on their own system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I paste this alpha image into a separate PNG image ( which has no
>   alpha ) in a new window in GIMP, the semi transparent pixels become
>   completely opaque.

I did reproduce your issue, **but** it only occured **if** pasting into an **indexed mode** new window, so you can fix this by pasting your image into a **RVB mode** new window instead.